# Convergence in Probability vs Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let X1, X2, . . . be independent identically distributed random variables with
P(X1 = 1) = P(X1 = −1) = 1/2. For any n ≥ 1, define

$S_n = \frac{X_1+...+X_2}{\sqrt{n}}$

The Central Limit Theorem says that Sn converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian random variable. We show that Sn does not converge in probability to any random variable.
The intuition here is that if Sn did converge in probability to a random variable Z, thenwhen n is large, Sn is close to Z, 
$Y_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}S_{2n} - S_n}{\sqrt{2}-1}$
is close to Z, but Sn and Yn are independent.
And this cannot happen.
Proceed as follows. Assume that Sn converges in probability to Z.

• Let ε > 0. For n very large (depending on ε), we have P(|Sn − Z| > ε) < ε and
P(|Yn − Z| > ε) < ε.

• Show that P(Sn > 0, Yn > 0) is around 1/4, using independence and the Central
Limit Theorem.

• From the first item, show P(Sn > 0|Z > ε) > 1 − ε, P(Yn > 0|Z > ε) > 1 − ε, so
P(Sn > 0, Yn > 0|Z > ε) > 1 − 2ε.

• Without loss of generality, for ε small, we have P(Z > ε) > 4/9.

• By conditioning on Z > ε, show that P(Sn > 0, Yn > 0) is at least 3/8, when n is
large.

I understand in the first part that you multiple the 2 probabilities because they are independent. Don't know how to get the results I want though. I'm stuck with the rest too.

Comment: It is not your fault:  The instructions seem wrong.  I think we agree on the first two bullets, but it is the third bullet that is strange:  The true third instruction bullet should be to show $P[S_n<0, Z>\epsilon] < \epsilon$, $P[Y_n<0, Z>\epsilon] <\epsilon$, so $P[\{S_n<0,  Z>\epsilon\} \cup \{Y_n<0, Z>\epsilon\}] < 2\epsilon$, so $P[\{S_n<0\} \cup \{Y_n<0\}|Z>\epsilon]< \frac{2\epsilon}{P[Z>\epsilon]}$ and $P[S_n\geq 0, Y_n\geq 0|Z>\epsilon] \geq 1 - \frac{2\epsilon}{P[Z>\epsilon]}$. Then you can use $P[Z>\epsilon] > 4/9$ to get a lower bound on $P[S_n>0, Y_n>0]$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood most of what you said, I'm now stuck at how to plug in the fact that P[Z>E] > 4/9 to the final equation we got from bullet point 3.

Comment: My guess is that $P(S_n>0,Y_n>0|z>\epsilon) > 1- 2\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$. Then solving the right side gives $\epsilon = \frac{3}{8}$?

Comment: You can ignore the $3/8$ thing, that seems irrelevant (likely it was in your instructions because it was based on an incorrect step).  Just multiply  $P[S_n\geq 0, Y_n \geq 0 | Z>\epsilon] \geq 1 - \frac{2\epsilon}{P[Z>\epsilon]}$ on both sides by $P[Z>\epsilon]$ and use the fact that $\epsilon$ is small.